# Date generator to table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I read about a way to generate a range of dates: [Generate a set or sequence without loops](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3). I'm having trouble with applying the method.

This code successfully generates a table of dates from `@Start` to `@End`:

```
;WITH d([Date]) AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @Start)
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Start, @End) + 1)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number) FROM master..spt_values
    ) AS x(n)
)
SELECT d.Date
FROM d
```

I'm fairly new to more advanced SQL so this is quite the black box. But it works. So now I wanted to save the result into a table variable for further processing:

```
DECLARE @Days TABLE ([Date] DATE NULL, Val INT NULL)
```

The date will have a value associated with it. However simply inserting into the table seems not to be working. Neither the following or wrapping it in yet another select statement works:

```
INSERT INTO @Days (Date)
WITH d([Date]) AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @Start)
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Start, @End) + 1)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number) FROM master..spt_values
    ) AS x(n)
)
SELECT d.Date
FROM d
```

It seems the 'last statement must be terminated with a semicolon' or an 'incorrect syntax near ;' is thrown depending on the presence of the semicolon.

Do you have any directions? I'm confused like mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not the CTE, it is the `INSERT` syntax.  As explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax), the CTE comes before the `INSERT`:

```
WITH d([Date]) AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @Start)
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Start, @End) + 1)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number) FROM master..spt_values
    ) AS x(n)
)
INSERT INTO @Days (Date)
    SELECT d.Date
    FROM d;
```